# How to technically send the query parameters to google cloud REST API?

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to call this [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/list)

How is one expected to add these params? maxResult
Page token
all
filter

How do I technically send the query parameters?

What part of the payload or options?

I couldn't find an example.

```
/**
 * Checks if dataset already exists in project.
 *
 * @return {boolean} Returns true if dataset already exists.
 */
function datasetExists() {
  // Get a list of all datasets in project.

  var url =
    'https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/${projectId}/datasets';

  var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',    
    payload: ""
  };
  var response = authUrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());


  Logger.log(result);
  if (result.entities) {
    Logger.log('Dataset with ID = %s created.', dataSet.id);
    // return a list of identified entities
    return result.entities;
  }
```

Comment: If you are checking the existence of a dataset, you should query this URL https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/{projectId}/datasets/{datasetId} (you are lacking the datasetId at the end). There is no query parameters to pass but path parameters: projectId and datasetId. Then check if response 200 or 404.

Comment: Thanks, if you go to the link I've added. How is one expected to add these params? maxResult
Page token
all 
filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the Google Cloud API use the same definition pattern.

- Path parameter, which is in the path of the url, like that

```
https://bigquery.googleapis.com/xxx/yyy/<pathparameters>/zzz
```

- Query parameters that come in the URL, but at the end, after a `?` and separated with `&`. Most of the time it's tokenPage, pageSize, filters,...

```
https://bigquery.googleapis.com/xxx/yyy/<pathparameters>/zzz?queryparam1=value1&queryparam2=value2
```

- The body to provide when you perform a POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE. in JSON (therefore you need to add the content type header when you use it).

Finally, in term of security, the APIs requires a `Bearer` Access Token in the `Authorization` header

Comment: How would you add an empty body? and non empty? under `payload: ""` ?

Comment: don't mention the payload in your object when your perform a GET.

Comment: or put what you want. with GET, the body is not provided